# Replace single line textbox with Dropdown on NewForm.aspx in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, replace

I have Single line of textbox on newform.aspx. I want to create runtime drodown on page load with some value using jquery in the place of single line textbox.

When user select value from dropdown it will goes to single line of textbox & when click on save button it is stored in list for same column.

Is that possible to do in sharepoint 2013?

Comment: Why not just use a drop down field and skip the textfield?

Comment: I want to use rest api to access list from other site to create dropdop

Comment: You mean a another site collection or just another subweb? If the list is on the root site and on a subweb you want to create this field, you could use a lookup field and point out the list in the parent (root). See tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziVngsLQ94w